# ReactJS: Parsing error: Export "NextQuestion" is not defined

Tags: reactjs, function, react-native, react-redux, helper

I'm confused as to why my arrow functions are not exporting. I've received the error "Parsing error: Export 'NextQuestion' is not defined" and I'm not sure why. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

NextQuestion = () => {
    var neww = true
    this.setState((state) => {
        return {continue: neww}
        }
    )
}

LostALife = () => {
    var newLives = this.state.lives - 1
    this.setState((state) => {
        return {lives: newLives}
        }
    )
}

export {NextQuestion, LostALife};
```

Comment: I have a doubt that you are using `this.setState` and `this.state` inside these methods, so if you've enclosed these methods in `class` component these will work as is. But if they are used outside of class component the implementation might not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your variables, use const NextQuestion, you can see the updated code below

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

const NextQuestion = () => {
    var neww = true
    this.setState((state) => {
        return {continue: neww}
        }
    )
}

const LostALife = () => {
    var newLives = this.state.lives - 1
    this.setState((state) => {
        return {lives: newLives}
        }
    )
}

export {NextQuestion, LostALife};
```

Comment: Hahaha -- I didnt know the error was that easy to fix. I'll also be sure to keep your answer in mind when this I do this again. Thanks a lot man! :D